# sudo:a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I am on jenkins and I am trying to build image of docker and I have already given permission by ''chmod 777 django-todo'' and I have already build image on local . Also i havent set any password.

Expected: build an image sucessfully

Comment: What's invoking the sudo command? Is sudo being run inside or outside the container?

Comment: You could configure the user who invokes sudo to do it without a password prompt